# jQuery show hide div

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to combine different scripts with no success. See below 1) 2) and 3).
I have combined 2) and 3) see column NEWS. Column UPCOMING uses 1) and works. I would like to combine the two functions. Both columns are working independently.

You can see my work (new site under construction, some fonts will be missing, photoshop work still to be done): http://www.brunovansina.be/wais/index2.htm

1) I have different divs. If one is clicked, other open div closes, only one can be open:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.show').click(function() {
        if ( !$(this).next('div').is(':visible') ) {
            $(".slidingDiv").slideUp();
            $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
        }
    });

    $('.hide').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().slideUp();
    });
});
```

2) If one div is opened I want to be able to close it by clicking again on it so none of the divs is open.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

3) when a link is clicked it changes color so you can see it's active. when clicked again, div closes and link returns inactive.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Thanx for any help, Bruno.

Comment: please post a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see the issue in action.

Comment: jsbin.com is another, I like it because it updates as you type

Comment: Why not just use jquery accordion - does exactly the thing you are looking for http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion